# JFileChooser to pick a directory or a single file

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

is it possible to make a JFileChooser which can choose a file or a directory?
Because, if I use a filefilter in my chooser it is only possible to choose the files included the filter option, but I am no longer able to choose a directory.

this is my JFileChooser

```
JFileChooser ch = new JFileChooser();
  ch.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
  ch.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

    public boolean accept(File f) {
      if (f != null && f.isDirectory()) {
        return true;
      }
      if (f == null || !f.getName().toUpperCase().endsWith(".PROPERTIES")) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
      return "Property Files" + " (*.properties)";
    }
  });
  ch.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
  ch.showOpenDialog(this);
  if (ch.getSelectedFile() != null) {
    ressource = ch.getSelectedFile();
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
  txtRessource.setText(ressource.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call

```
ch.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```

And that way you will be able to select either a file or a directory. This works with combination of your filter.

Btw you don't have to implement the file filter too, there is a [FileNameExtensionFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) which does exactly what you want (it also accepts folders):

```
ch.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Properties file", "properties"));
```

Answer (score 2):

To select files and directories try this

```
file_chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```

And to choose only directories try this

```
dir_chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

**REASON**
As the name suggests, adding a file filter will only filter out a ceratin types of files and will allow you to choose only particular type of file like .jpg,.png etc if you want to select only image files. But to select a directory or only a file you have to set the file selection mode of the JFileChooser instance. Set the mode according to your requirements.

Comment: i know this option (setFileSelectionMode). But it dosn't work in combination with setFileFilter. I tried it before, and i got the same result. It have to be a way, to choose a directory or a file.

Comment: It's also worth noting that FILES_ONLY will still allow you to see directories, you just cannot select them.
If you want to allow only some directories, you need to use `JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES` then write a filter that returns `true` on the directories you care about.

Comment: Its obvious. The name FILES_ONLY means that only files can be selected. Since he needs both together so I have edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Dude was looking for the answer of this as well. I think its too late to tell you, but for anyone looking I think adding file.isDirectory() == true on the filter work. So in this case if you are looking to choose files ending with .Properties then

```
  public boolean accept(File f) {
  if (f.isDirectory() || f.getName().toUpperCase().endsWith(".PROPERTIES")) {
    return true;
  }
```

So in this case if its either a file directory or something that ends with a properties extension